# How to validate an editable column?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm new in Thymeleaf and try to create a contenteditable table.

So for now I have table where I put Users after adding (using controller). When I press the button "Edit" colums become editable (by using "contenteditable="true"), then I want to VALIDATE text that I'm putting over there and after successful validation save it by pressing on the button "Save" (change to "contenteditable="false"). When you see "Edit", "Save" is hidden.

I tried to create a trivial validation for Name, Phone and Email but it's not working... And also I have this on "MyFirstName" and otherss: "Argument type HTMLElement is not assignable to parameter type string" (probably there is the problem). And I don't know how to validate length of Phone Number here as well..

If you have any ideas how to make it works, please, help me, cause I'm trying very long time..

P.S. I can only use this HTML page and insert there JS-code.

Thank you!!

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
...
<table id="myTable">
<tr  th:each ="user : ${users}">
   <td th:text="${user.id}" ></td> <input type="text" id="message"/>
   <td th:text="${user.firstName}" id="firstName" contenteditable="false" ></td>
   <td th:text="${user.lastName}" id="lastName" contenteditable="false" ></td>
   <td th:text="${user.phoneNumber}" id="phoneNumber" contenteditable="false" ></td>
   <td th:text="${user.email}" id="email" contenteditable="false" ></td>
   <td>
       <button type="button" id="edit_button" onclick="Edit()">Edit</button>
       <button type="button" id="save_button" style="display: none" onclick="Save()">Save</button>
  </td>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                   $("#edit_button").click(function () {
                       $("#edit_button").hide();
                       $("#save_button").show();
                   });
               </script>
               <script type="text/javascript">

                   function Edit() {
                       let editable = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=false]")
                       editable[0].setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
                       editable[1].setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
                       editable[2].setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
                       editable[3].setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
                   }

                   function Save() {

                       let editable = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
                       let myFirstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
                       let myLastName = document.getElementById("LastName");
                       let myPhoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
                       let myEmail = document.getElementById("email");
                       let re1 = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
                       let valid1 = re1.test(myFirstName);
                       let re2 = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
                       let valid2 = re2.test(mySurName);
                       let re3 = /^\d[\d\(\)\ -]{4,14}\d$/;
                       let valid3 = re3.test(myPhone);
                       let re4 = /^[\w-\.]+@[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
                       let valid4 = re4.test(myEmail);
                       if (valid1 && valid2 && valid3 && valid4){
                           $("#save_button").hide();
                           $("#edit_button").show();
                           editable[0].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
                           editable[1].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
                           editable[2].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
                           editable[3].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
                       } else {
                           alert('Type correct information!');
                       }

                   }
               </script>
</tr>
       </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to validate the value of the element and not the element itself. Like `let valid1 = re1.test(myFirstName?.textContent);` or change the assignment to `let myFirstName = document.getElementById("firstName")?.textContent;`. Also be aware that `contenteditable` allows users to totally mess up your whole HTML and to copy/paste whatever they feel like with weird formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's working i used `let valid1 = re1.test(myFirstName?.textContent);` , but I cannot put correct informapion, seems like something wrong with regular expression, it's always `alert('Type correct information!')` Can you take a look at them and see what's wrong? @Lain

Comment: Your regular expressions seem to work as defined. Maybe not as you want to, but that I can not judge/help you with. However, if I enter `['aZ', 'aZ', '0000000000', 'a@a.com']` it validates to `true`.

Comment: Thank you again! No, it works as I need, there was just one another problem which I fixed now... Now users cannot edit evetything, only columns! So I will add Answer for future:) @Lain

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  The question contains nothing about the jQuery Validate plugin and therefore should not have used this tag.  Edited.